# StackOverFlow with (alt+0160)

Tags: c#, .net, search, directory, alt

I created folder with no name using (alt + 0160) while I search with c# it stuck in infinite loop and create exception of "Stack Over Flow"
My method is given which i am using for Search.

```
public void getTotatFoldersAndFilesCount(DirectoryInfo objDirs, System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker)
        {
            try{
                  if (worker.CancellationPending == true)
                {  return;  }
                FileInfo[] objFiles = null;
                numFoldersCount++;
                if ((objDirs.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != 0)
                { return;}
                try
                {
                    objFiles = objDirs.GetFiles(searchPatteren);
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                {         }
                catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
                {         }
                catch (System.StackOverflowException ex)
                {             }
                if (objFiles != null)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo objFile in objFiles)
                    {
                     numFilesCount++;
                    }
                    foreach (DirectoryInfo objDir in objDirs.GetDirectories())
                    {
                        getTotatFoldersAndFilesCount(objDir, worker);
                    }
                }
                objFiles = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogger("Error in Total Folder and File Count - Directory Name: " + objDirs.Name);
                ErrorLogger(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My search stuck in infinite loop .I want to know how and why..??

Comment: Have you tried to debug? Maybe start with a visible folder. What does objDirs.GetDirectories() return. Etc.

Comment: By the way, it's not possible to catch a `StackOverflowException`. It is one of the few you can't recover from.

Comment: Change the name of your folder!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be avoided by a simple change:
In the directory enumeration code, change the for loop to:

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo objDir in new DirectoryInfo(objDirs.FullName + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).GetDirectories(searchPatteren))
{
    getTotatFoldersAndFilesCount(objDir, worker);
}
```

When enumerating blank folder, the directory name is a white space. When initializing the DirectoryInfo object, the whitespace is trimmed causing the function to always loop trough the same directory. Adding the DirectorySeperatorChar ("\") in most of the cases solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I google this question and find the solution by given link.

by adding single slash at the end of the directory path it will not go into infinite loop.
first i was doing this.

```
getTotatFoldersAndFilesCount(objDir, worker);
```

and now replace it with this. It solved my problem,

```
 DirectoryInfo nDI = new DirectoryInfo(objDir.FullName + @"\");
                        getTotatFoldersAndFilesCount(nDI, worker);
```

link is given.
http://tiku.io/questions/4277530/getdirectories-fails-to-enumerate-subfolders-of-a-folder-with-255-name